# Why does OpenLDAP not auto add inheritied objectclasses

Tags: openldap

I'm running into an issue, I'm attempting to add users with the following ldif;

```
dn: mail=jsmith,ou=customers,dc=mydeqcust,dc=org
cn: John Smith
sn: Smith
uid: jsmith
mail: jsmith@dev.local
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
mail: jsmith
```

it adds fine, however when I look at the record, I see that it only has the attributes from inetOrgPerson, not orginzationalperson or person, even though I verified in the slapd.d schema's that they are properly inheriting. If I add the additional objectClass for each one it works fine.

My understanding was that openldap would automatically go through the hierarchy and add the additional classes.
I'm running

```
root@LNX-mydeq-dev-ldap-02 tmp]# slapd -V
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.39 (Aug 16 2014 20:41:55) $
```

Comment: I don't know what kind of an answer you're expecting to this question here. It should be addressed to the OpenLDAP developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly get what's the problem – the inheritance is implicitly handled, you don't need to enumerate any of the classes that were pulled by inetOrgPerson.

Comment: No it doesn't. Some clients, e.g. JXplorer, do that for you. The server doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, just got back to this. This is exactly correct, Jxplorer just doesn't show it, however all attributets are available. I just didn't test it in the right way

Comment: @GardenMWM JXplorer will show whatever is there. It doesn't suppress objectClasses, or anything else except operational attributes, which you can display via the Properties option.